# Why are the roots of a discriminant system called singularities in homotopy continuation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

In the article [Introduction To Numerical Algebraic Geometry](https://janv.people.uic.edu/Articles/intro.pdf), the authors state on page six that

> The singularities along the solution paths are solutions of the system
> $\begin{cases}h(x, y, t) &= 0\\\det(J_h(x, y, t)) &= 0\end{cases}$.

Why are solutions to the "discriminant system" singularities of the solution pahts? Is it because $h(x, y, t)$ does not have an inverse mapping at those points as determinant of its Jacobian is zero? If that is the case, why is it necessary for $h(x, y, t)$ to also vanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because yes, the regular case is that at some point of the path $h(x,y,t)=0$ you can compute a unique tangent vector $(x_x,v_y)$ from $$∂_xh(x,y,t)v_x+∂_yh(x,y,t)v_y+∂_th(x,y,t)=0.$$ This requires that the Jacobian $\frac{\partial h}{\partial(x,y)}$ has a non-vanishing determinant, is a non-singular matrix.

At non-regular, that is, singular points, there may be multiple tangent directions (for instance, if two paths cross), the tangent can become vertical (path has a fold, only way to continue is to change direction in $t$) or some other forms.

---

The central block of most (or all?) root-finding algorithms is a local solver. This lies in the nature of the task, computers are finite, so what an algorithm can do is compute values and derivatives in a finite number of points, establish a model of some simple nature from that data, and extend the search by the roots of the model. For instance,

- Newton uses value and derivative in the last point,
- the secant method uses values in the last two points,
- regula falsi uses values with modifiers in the last bracketing interval, that is, the last two points with a sign change in the values, etc.

This data, however many points it uses, is incomplete (except for polynomial systems). The local model can deviate unpredictably from the given function. This error reduces if the function is smooth enough and the sample points are close to the root.

The homotopy idea now is a heuristic to replace one root-finding task with a large distance from initial guess to a solution with a series of root-finding task with controlled small distances. For instance for a system $F(X)=0$ one could consider the homotopy
$$
H(X,t)=(1-t)F(X_0)+tF(X)+t(1-t)G(X).
$$
The local problems to solve are then $H(X_k,k\Delta t)=0$ using $X_0$ as guess for the first step, and then the solution (approximation) $X_{k-1}$ of the last step as initial guess for the next step. If $Δt$ is small enough, this guess $X_{k-1}$ is still in the region of guaranteed convergence of the method for the next solution $X_k$.

For most methods, to get a basin of convergence with a positive radius above some minimum requires that the Jacobian $\frac{\partial H}{\partial X}$ is some minimal distance away from the set of singular matrices. Otherwise said, to get a singular Jacobian on the path presents an obstacle for the continuation of the method. Often a randomly chosen function $G$ will be sufficient to ensure this condition.

Comment: I am bit rusty with my multivariable calculus. Could you either explain me briefly or point to an appropriate theorem which explains why at $h(x, y, t) = 0$ we can find in the regular case a unique tangent vector (as you wrote). Specifically, I am trying to understand why $h(x, y, t) = 0$ is significant.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a system $u(x,y)=v(x,y)=0$. Then you construct an homotopy like $$h(x,y,t)=(tu(x,y)+(1-t)u(x_0,y_0)+at(1-t),\,tv(x,y)+(1-t)v(x_0,y_0)+bt(1-t))$$ where you know that $h(x_0,y_0,0)=0$. Then increasing $t$ in small amounts, you try to find solutions to $h(x_t,y_t,t)=0$ so that $(x_1,y_1)$ is a solution to the original system. The idea is that with choosing the increment $dt$ small, $(x_{t+dt},y_{t+dt})$ is close to $(x_t,y_t)$. Most root-finding methods base their local convergence on the fact that the Jacobian is regular close to the solution.